# Expect or are expecting

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

This passage is from "Macmillan English Grammar in Context" by Michael Vince.
"They are still examining the wreckage of the high speed train. They don't believe the accident involves driver error. We expect to publish an inquiry into this accident quite soon", a spokesman announced yesterday."
Should I use "expect" or "Are expecting"?

Answer (score 1):

I believe both are acceptable. The difference being in the tense: "expect" is Simple Present (true at this moment), and "are expecting" is Present Continuous (every moment).

Regards